# How to divide a tensor elements to specific indixes

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor like this:

```
out = [[ 3,  6,  5,  4],
       [ 6,  5, 10, 13],
       [ 5, 10,  6, 22],
       [ 4, 13, 22,  9]]
```

And this is a symmetrical matrix. What I want to do is to divide each element by the values in the same indexes of diagonal. So the values of diagonal in this matrix are:

```
index0 = 3
index1 = 5
index2 = 6
index3 = 9
```

The result will look like this:

```
[[3      ,  6/(3*5) ,  5/(3*6) ,  4/(3*9) ]
 [6/(3*5),  5       ,  10/(5*6),  13/(5*9)]
 [5/(3*6),  10/(5*6),  6       ,  22/(6*9)]
 [4/(3*9),  13/(5*9),  22/(6*9),  9       ]]
```

Let me walk through the first row:

`3` is the value in the diagonal so we will skip it

`6/3*5`, `6` is the value at `index 0 and 1` so that I will divide `6` by the diagonal values in `index0 and 1`.

`5/3*6`, `5` is the value at index `0 and 2` so that I will divide it by diagonal values at index `0 and 2`

`4/3*9`, `4` is the value at index `0 and 3` so that I will divide it by diagonal values at index `0 and 3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be done as following in tensorflow (or numpy).

1. We take the original matrix and zero out diagonal.
2. We divide the resulted matrix by diagonal vector.
3. We transpose result from 2 and divide it again by diagonal vector.
4. We add diagonal that we zeroed out in step 1.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

out = [[ 3,  6,  5,  4],
       [ 6,  5, 10, 13],
       [ 5, 10,  6, 22],
       [ 4, 13, 22,  9]]

tensor = tf.constant(out, dtype=tf.float32)

diag_indices = tf.tile(tf.range(tf.shape(tensor)[0])[..., None], [1, 2])
diag = tf.gather_nd(tensor, diag_indices) # [3. 5. 6. 9.]

diag_matrix = tf.linalg.tensor_diag(diag)
zero_diag_matrix = tensor - diag_matrix
res = tf.transpose(zero_diag_matrix / diag) / diag + diag_matrix

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(res.eval())
# [[3.         0.4        0.27777776 0.14814815]
#  [0.4        5.         0.33333334 0.28888887]
#  [0.27777776 0.3333333  6.         0.4074074 ]
#  [0.14814815 0.28888887 0.4074074  9.        ]]
```

Comment: Great! Much simpler

Comment: @Vlad Thank you so much, I was wondering can we do this using `scatter_nd` as well?

Comment: @sariii, Not in any trivial way. I think it will only overcomplicate things here.

Comment: I see I was trying to do it by `scatter_nd` but could not. your solution looks simple and understandable, Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Using numpy, you could do as follows:

```
import numpy as np

out = out.astype(float)
# diagonal elements in out
d = np.copy(np.diagonal(out))
# Indices of lower triangular matriX
tril_ix = np.tril_indices_from(out, k=-1)
# cumulative sum of the diagonal values
# over the first axis on a square matrix
dx = np.cumsum(np.diag(d), 1) 
# replicate ove lower triangular
dx[tril_ix] += np.rot90(dx, k=1)[::-1][tril_ix]
# same but accumulating the diagonal elements
# upwards on the y axis
dy = np.cumsum(np.diag(d)[::-1],0)[::-1]
# replicate ove rlower triangular
dy[tril_ix] += np.rot90(dy, k=1)[::-1][tril_ix]
# mask where to apply the product
m = dy!=0
# perform div and mult
out[m] = out[m]/(dx[m]*dy[m])
np.fill_diagonal(out, d)
```

---

```
print(out)

array([[3.        , 0.4       , 0.27777778, 0.14814815],
       [0.4       , 5.        , 0.33333333, 0.28888889],
       [0.27777778, 0.33333333, 6.        , 0.40740741],
       [0.14814815, 0.28888889, 0.40740741, 9.        ]])
```

Comment: it was a shock to see that tensorflow doesn't support item assignment to tensor slices while solving this problem. Well, numpy does it! Do you have any idea how to solve it in a vectorized manner in tensorflow?

Comment: No, don't know enough tf for this, I was hoping that you could find a numpy approach useful :) @TirthPatel

Comment: sure, it's helpful but tensorflow is usually a choice for performing automatic differentiation in a deep learning or machine learning model on GPU. I think that tensorflow can only differentiate through the operations performed using tensorflow functions on tensorflow tensors. numpy operations break the auto diff library to perform differentiation. It would be nice to see a tensorflow version once they support item assignment on tensor slices.

Comment: I see what you'll be needing this for now, and yes having it in numpy would be problematic @TirthPatel Will leave it here in case someone finds it useful to adapt to tf, or yourself?

Comment: I am confused myself. Let's leave it to some tf veteran :)

Comment: Take a look at my solution, guys. Same could be applied in numpy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tensorflow version.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

out = tf.Variable([[ 3,  6,  5,  4],
                   [ 6,  5, 10, 13],
                   [ 5, 10,  6, 22],
                   [ 4, 13, 22,  9]], dtype=tf.float32)

# this solution only works for square matrices
assert out.shape[-2] == out.shape[-1]

out_diag = tf.linalg.diag_part(out)
res = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(out.shape, dtype=tf.float32))

for i in tf.range(out.shape[0]):
    _ = res[..., (i+1):, i].assign(out[..., (i+1):, i] / out_diag[..., (i+1):] / out_diag[..., i])
    _ = res[..., i, (i+1):].assign(out[..., i, (i+1):] / out_diag[..., (i+1):] / out_diag[..., i])

print(res)
```

Comment: Tahnk you so much, For some reason I can not use `for loop` but thanks for posting the solution

Comment: You're Welcome @sarii. ``tf.for`` loop works for me in tensorflow 2.x versions on Windows and Linux machines. What tensorflow version are you using?

Comment: I am using `tf 14` though the reason is that my matrix is gonna be large. I would like not loop cause of performance issue